# Link to EditForm of Document Library item in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, microsoft-graph, edit-form

I need to send an email to users containing documents in a document library that lack necessary metadata. The list of items is generated using Microsoft Graph.
The `WebUrl` property that Graph exposes leads directly to the item, but I need to link to the EditForm so the user can easily fill in the missing information.

I alreay tried a link of the format `https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/[Site]/[DocumentLibrary]/Forms/EditForm.aspx?id=[ID]` as mentioned in older answers. On some sites it leads to an error page, on others it shows a broken version of the document library with all items missing. None of the links work.
[image]

How can I link to the EditForm of a document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Form Link for SharePoint Edit/Display forms, Query string parameter for "ID" is case sensitive so use **ID** instead of "**id**"

https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/[Site]/[DocumentLibrary]/Forms/EditForm.aspx?**ID**=[ID]

Comment: That works! Such a simple fix... Thank you very much!